# Dict to Dataframe conversion is getting one row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a excel file using Pandas and it loaded as Dict. I am trying to convert to dataframe but I am getting only one row in dataframe. How do I get all rows into dataframe.
Is something wrong with excel or with my code? Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
path = path to excel file
data = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=[1])
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()))
```

If I print data I am seeing all rows in dict.

```
{1:     LINE  ... Coverage Status
0    E01  ...             NaN
1    E02  ...             NaN
2    E03  ...             NaN
3    E04  ...             NaN
4    E05  ...             NaN
..   ...  ...             ...
317    U  ...     Not Offered
318    U  ...     Not Offered
319    V  ...     Not Offered
320   VV  ...     Not Offered
321    W  ...     Not Offered

[322 rows x 22 columns]}
```

If I print df, I see only one row.

```
   0                                                  1
0  1      LINE  ... Coverage Status
0    E01  ...   ...
```

Comment: try `df = data[1]`

Comment: `data` is a dict of dataframes (in this case of size 1). Try to use `df = data[1]` .

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 is returning the Dataframe you want, so just remove the fourth line and you should be set. In line 4 you converted your dictionary into a list of the dict keys and values
using the .items() method. Passing a list into a Dataframe will return a Dataframe with only one column.

```
data = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=[1])
```